# TextFormField increase height with proper alignment

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my `TextFormField` 'bigger'. I tried this code, it does make it bigger, but if I type (here: qwerty) it starts in the middle. Is there an option to start in the left upper corner?

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Container(
    width: screenWidth / 1.1,
    height: screenHeight / 5.5,
    child: Form(
      key: _form2Key,
      autovalidate: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (val) {
          if (val.trim().length > 200) {
            return "Beschrijving te lang";
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
        onSaved: (val) => beschrijving = val,
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: null,
        expands: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          labelText: "",
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          hintText: " ",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image: screenshot code in IOS simulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Container(
    width: 400,
    height: 120,
    child: Form(
      autovalidate: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        validator: (val) {
          if (val.trim().length > 200)
            return "Beschrijving te lang";
          else
            return null;
        },
        maxLines: 100,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          labelText: "",
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          hintText: "Enter a message",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in mycase this is how i solved it.
you could ommit the  `keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,`  in order to allow one to move to the next line.(enter)

```
 TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  controller: _description,
                  maxLines: 10,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintMaxLines: 10,
                      hintText: "description",
                      labelText: "Description",
                      hintStyle: hintText),
                ),
```